# JVM heap - why S0/S1 size decreases over time?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We have a java server application which is producing a lot of temporary data, thus consuming a lot of time in GC. We are trying to fine tune its JVM settings for best performance. Currently our jvm settings are: `java -server -Xmx45700m -Xms34275m -XX:InitialTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:NewSize=32132m -XX:SurvivorRatio=4`

We set higher survivor ratio in order to prevent this temp data from being moved to the old generation area.

The weird behavior that we see is that over time the S0/S1 sizes decrease from the configured size of 5G to less than 1G.

This is from the beginning of the application lifetime:
Heap

```
 PSYoungGen      total 27419648K, used 9887259K [0x00007ff819f80000, 0x00007ffff2380000, 0x00007ffff2380000)
  eden space 21936128K, 44% used [0x00007ff819f80000,0x00007ffa6773e488,0x00007ffd54d80000)
  from space 5483520K, 4% used [0x00007ffea3880000,0x00007ffeb18489f0,0x00007ffff2380000)
  to   space 5483520K, 0% used [0x00007ffd54d80000,0x00007ffd54d80000,0x00007ffea3880000)
 ParOldGen       total 2194432K, used 104K [0x00007ff4c9f80000, 0x00007ff54fe80000, 0x00007ff819f80000)
  object space 2194432K, 0% used [0x00007ff4c9f80000,0x00007ff4c9f9a018,0x00007ff54fe80000)
 PSPermGen       total 37376K, used 37233K [0x00007ff4c4d80000, 0x00007ff4c7200000, 0x00007ff4c9f80000)
  object space 37376K, 99% used [0x00007ff4c4d80000,0x00007ff4c71dc418,0x00007ff4c7200000)

And this is after some time:
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 32397312K, used 4399893K [0x00007ff819f80000, 0x00007ffff2380000, 0x00007ffff2380000)
  eden space 31891456K, 12% used [0x00007ff819f80000,0x00007ff907a4cbc0,0x00007fffb4780000)
  from space 505856K, 99% used [0x00007fffb4780000,0x00007fffd35788b8,0x00007fffd3580000)
  to   space 505856K, 0% used [0x00007fffd3580000,0x00007fffd3580000,0x00007ffff2380000)
 ParOldGen       total 2194432K, used 774462K [0x00007ff4c9f80000, 0x00007ff54fe80000, 0x00007ff819f80000)
  object space 2194432K, 35% used [0x00007ff4c9f80000,0x00007ff4f93cfa40,0x00007ff54fe80000)
 PSPermGen       total 45568K, used 45222K [0x00007ff4c4d80000, 0x00007ff4c7a00000, 0x00007ff4c9f80000)
  object space 45568K, 99% used [0x00007ff4c4d80000,0x00007ff4c79a9900,0x00007ff4c7a00000)
```

Why did it decrease from 5G to 0.5G ?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using the Parallel collector, which has throughput as its goal.

Copying 5GB of objects back and forth between the survivor spaces several times most likely is wasted CPU cycles if only a small percentage of objects dies with each tenuring interval.
So the GC shrinks the survivor spaces and copies them to the old generation sooner to avoid repeated costs in the hope that a rare old gen GC will be much more efficient in terms of CPU cycles spent relative to the number of garbage collected, i.e. to improve throughput.

Your old gen only has 2GB worth of objects at this point. Collecting this once in a while is much cheaper than GCing 5GB worth of objects several times.

The huge young generation seems very odd in general. Have you actually done measurements and confirmed that this improves anything?